# Jstree custom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jstree

We have a project with `jstree 1.0-rc3`. To extend basic funtionality we wrote custom extention using `JQuery.jstree.plugin()` function. Other words, we created custom plugin and used it as a usual plugin. Recently we decided to update jstree version to latest (3.3.8) and I met trouble because this function (JQuery.jstree.plugin) do not exist anymore and I can not find any analogue. Because of size of our custom plugin (hundreds of lines) and big count of place where we use it we do not want to move functionality to some another place from custom plugin cause it will take a really lot of time. Does anyone know how is it possible to create custom plugin in latest `jstree ( 3.3.8 now)`? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality to add custom plugin is still there in the current jsTree version (3.3.8). As an example, it is already explained

```
// conditional select
(function ($, undefined) {
  "use strict";
  $.jstree.defaults.conditionalselect = function () { return true; };
  $.jstree.plugins.conditionalselect = function (options, parent) {
    this.activate_node = function (obj, e) {
      if(this.settings.conditionalselect.call(this, this.get_node(obj))) {
        parent.activate_node.call(this, obj, e);
      }
    };
  };
})(jQuery);
$("#tree").jstree({
  "conditionalselect" : function (node) {
    return node.text === "Root node" ? false : true;
  },
  "plugins" : ["conditionalselect"]
});
```

Please the approach explained in https://github.com/vakata/jstree#more-plugins how to included your own plugin or any third party plugins.You must include its source on the page and list its name in the "plugins" config array.

You can have a look at jstree/src/misc.js for finding many such custom plugins already written.